# Problems with custom alignment of Listcontent

Tags: css

I neew Help:

I try a lot of things but nothing works very well. I want to get the Text like "Sympany Hauptsitz" centre and Nan KM a little bit downside.

How can i change the position from the Text?

Here is a picture of my problem.

[image]

I had this source code:

Here my Sourcecode:

```
<section id="listview">
<ul class="liste">

</ul>
</section>

<script>
//laden der json datei und befüllen der Tabelle
$.getJSON('faddress.json', function(json){
var erg = json;
$.each(json, function(i, daten){
//Kartenausschnitt
var ausschnitt = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=50x50&markers=color:blue|size:tiny|'+daten.Position.Latitude+','+daten.Position.Longitude+'&sensor=true';

$('#listview').find('ul.liste').append('<li><img src="'+ausschnitt+'">'+ i +'<span>'+ entfernungBerechnen(mylongitude,mylatitude,daten.Position.Longitude,daten.Position.Latitude )+'</span></li>');
});
});
</script>
```

And this Sytelsheet:

```
ul.liste {
padding: 0;
margin: 9px;
list-style: none;
border: 1px solid #a1a7ad;
border-radius: 8px;

font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

ul.liste li {
background: #f7f7f7;
border-top: 1px solid #fdfdfd;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
padding: 5px 10px;
line-height: 30px;
font-size:12px;
height: 50px;
}

ul.liste li:first-child {
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-color: #e5e5e5;
}

ul.liste li:last-child {
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

ul.liste li span {
float: right;
display: block;
color: #999;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your page at all. Which javascript library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The #1 rule for styling lists:**

Use `display:block` on the `A`-tag and put all non-positional styling on the A-tag, not the `LI`.

For LI only use: `display:` `position:` and `float:`, the rest goes on A.

Comment: Sry? What do you mean with a_tag? i already try display pos and float it dowsnt work very well .....

Comment: Don't style the list - style the CONTENTS of the list. Style the links, not the wrappers.

Comment: You may find it easier to apply the image to the background of the link and use padding:left to move the text, rather than using an img tag.